# Node.js server with multiple concurrent requests, how does it work?

Tags: node.js, nonblocking, single-threaded

I know node.js is a single threaded, asynchronous, non blocking i/o. I've read a lot about that. e.g PHP uses one thread per request but node uses only one thread for all, like that.

Suppose there are three requests a, b, c arriving at same time at node.js server. Three of these requests require large blocking operation e.g they all want to read same big file.

Then how are the requests queued, in what sequence will the blocking operation be carried out and in what sequences are the responses dispatched? Of course using how many threads?

Please tell me the sequences from request to response for three requests.

Comment: Node's runtime IS multithreaded. It's only the Javascript model that runs a single thread.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Here's a description of a sequence of events for your three requests:**

1. Three requests are sent to the node.js web server.
2. Whichever request arrives fractionally before the other two will trigger the web server request handler and it will start executing.
3. The other two requests go into the node.js event queue, waiting their turn.  It's technically up to the internals of the node.js implementation whether a waiting request is queued at the incoming TCP level or whether it's queued inside of node.js (I don't actually know), but for the purposes of this discussion, all that matters is that the incoming event is queued and won't trigger until the first request stops running.
4. That first request handler will execute until it hits an asynchronous operation (such as reading a file) and then has nothing else to do until the async operation completes.
5. At that point, the async file I/O operation is initiated and that original request handler returns (it is done with what it can do at that moment).
6. Since the first request (which is waiting for file I/O) has returned for now, the node.js engine can now pull the next event out of the event queue and start it.  This will be the second request to arrive on the server.  It will go through the same process at the first request and will run until it has nothing else to do (and is also waiting for file I/O).
7. When the second requests returns back to the system (because it's waiting for file I/O), then the third request can start running.  It will follow the same path as the previous two.
8. When the third request is now also waiting for I/O and returns back to the system, node.js is then free to pull the next event out of the event queue.
9. At this point, all three request handlers are "in flight" at the same time.  Only one ever actually runs at once, but all are in process at once.
10. This next event in the event queue could be some other event or some other request or it could be the completion of one of the three previous file I/O operations.  Whichever event is next in the queue will start executing.  Suppose it's the first request's file I/O operation.  At that point, it calls the completion callback associated with that first request's file I/O operation and that first request starts processing the file I/O results.  This code will then continue to run until it either finishes the entire request and returns or until it starts some other async operation (like more file I/O) and returns.
11. Eventually, the second request's file I/O will be ready and that event will be pulled from the event queue.
12. Then, the same for the third request and eventually all three will finish.

So, even though only one request ever is actually executing at the same time, multiple requests can be "in process" or "in flight" at the same time.  This is sometimes called cooperative multi-tasking in that rather than "pre-emptive" multitasking with multiple, native threads where the system can freely switch between threads at any moment, a given thread of Javascript runs until it returns back to the system and then, and only then, can another piece of Javascript start running.  Because a piece of Javascript can initiate non-blocking asynchronous operations, the thread of Javascript can return back to the system (enabling other pieces of Javascript to run) while it's asynchronous operations are still pending.  When those operations completes, they will post an event to the event queue and when other Javascript is done and that event gets to the top of the queue, it will run.

**Single Threaded**

The key point here is that a given thread of Javascript will run until it returns back to the system.  If, in the process of executing, it starts some asynchronous operations (such as file I/O or networking), then when those events finish, they will put an event in the event queue and when the JS engine is done running any events before it, that event will be serviced and will cause a callback to get called and that callback will get its turn to execute.

This single threaded nature vastly simplifies how concurrency is handled vs. a multi-threaded model.  In a fully multi-threaded environment where every single request starts its own thread, then ANY data that wishes to be shared, even a simple variable is subject to a race condition and must be protected with a mutex before anyone can even just read it.

In Javascript because there is no concurrent execution of multiple requests, no mutex is needed for simple shared variable access.  At the point one piece of Javascript is reading a variable, by definition, no other Javascript is running at that moment (single threaded).

**Node.js Does Use Threads**

One technical distinction of note is that only the execution of your Javascript is single threaded.  The node.js internals do use threads themselves for some things.  For example, asynchronous file I/O actually uses native threads.  Network I/O does not actually use threads (it uses native event driven networking).

But, this use of threads in the internals of node.js does not affect the Javascript execution directly.  There is still only ever one single thread of Javascript executing at a time.

**Race Conditions**

There still can be race conditions for state that is in the middle of being modified when an async operation is initiated, but this is way, way less common than in a multi-threaded environment and it is much easier to identify and protect these cases.  As an example of a race condition that can exist, I have a simple server that takes readings from several temperature probes every 10 seconds using an interval timer.  It collects the data from all those temperature readings and every hour it writes out that data to disk.  It uses async I/O to write the data to disk.  But, since a number of different async file I/O operations are used to write the data to disk, it is possible for the interval timer to fire in between some of those async file I/O operations causing the data that the server is in the middle of writing to disk to be modified.  This is bad and can cause inconsistent data to be written.  In a simple world, this could be avoided by making a copy of all the data before it starts writing it to disk so if a new temperature reading comes in while the data is being written to disk, the copy will not be affected and the code will still write a consistent set of data to disk.  But, in the case of this server, the data can be large and the memory on the server is small (it's a Raspberry Pi server) so it is not practical to make an in-memory copy of all the data.

So, the problem is solved by setting a flag when the data is in the process of being written to disk and then clearing the flag when data is done being written to disk.  If an interval timer fires while this flag is set, the new data is put into a separate queue and the core data that is in the process of being written to disk is NOT modified.  When the data is done being written to disk, it checks the queue and any temperature data it finds there is then added to the in-memory temperature data.  The integrity of what is in the process of being written to disk is preserved.  My server logs an event any time this "race condition" is hit and data is queued because of it.  And, lo and behold, it does happen every once in a while and the code to preserve the integrity of the data works.

Comment: Suppose large number of requests (say 500) hit the server before I/O operations of three earlier requests complete which means 500 new requests are there in the the event queue OK! So response for the first 3 request will be pending because of those 500 new requests.Is it good?

Comment: @Siddharth - One would have to test how node.js prioritizes I/O completion events vs. incoming new connection events.  Conceptually, this should not be a problem whichever way it works, but I don't know which events get priority in the way node.js handles things.  Logically, one would think it would prioritize serving connections that have already started, but you'd either have to write up a test case and run it on several node.js platforms or study the source code to know for sure.

Comment: @jfriend00 hi I don't have formal computer training but I see alot of the letters `I/o` I would appreciate if you can explain a little about it. like when you use it in this sentence: `the async file I/O operation is initiated` do you mean that this is the point of time that the interpreter or what ever it's called reads the file that the OP is talking? Why are calling it an "async file" ? btw I think that I/O mean input/ output. and that means operations that are being applied to something.  And when people mention it for node it is mostly req and responses(servers)? any answer will help

Comment: @jackblank - I/O means input/output.  It's a shortcut for reading or writing data from external sources (disk, network or other peripherals).  `Initiated` means that node.js tells some sub-system to start reading the file in the background while other processing continues (that's how async reading works).  The sub-system will then call a callback when data has been read.

Comment: so if we don't have I/O async operations, but we have long running (like 3-4 seconds each) synchronous requests, and 500 of them come within a period of 1 or 2 seconds, what happens? the 500th of them has to wait about 499*3 = 1497 seconds to be served because the 499 are going to be seved sequentially? Even if 31 or 63 or 127 other threads are sleeping because nodejs doesn't bother using them?

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis - I don't know what you mean by 127 other threads sleeping.  Nodejs only runs one thread for your Javascript and a few other threads for some system operations.  If you have 500 simultaneous requests of all synchronous work, then you should run a clustered node.js that uses as many clusters as you have actual CPU cores on your server.  That's how you set up node.js to take maximal advantage of the cores on your CPU.  But, it's very rare to have tons of requests that aren't bound by I/O.  There's nearly always file I/O or database I/O involved.

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis - The cluster module is built into nodejs and pretty easy to use.  You can also use `WorkerThreads` and fire up your own threads for synchronous operations if you want.  There are lots of choices if you have 100% synchronous work to do.

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis - Just came across this interesting article about node.js and blocking the event loop: [Don't Block the Event Loop (or the Worker Pool)](https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/).  It might be helpful for you.